# Query to update missing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns what I need to do is a query that set values to `SP_REFSTART2`, `SP_REFSTOP2` if `SP_REFSTART` and `SP_REFSTOP` ARE NOT NULL else if the 2 first columns are null I want those values to fill the first two columns.

```
SP_REFSTART | SP_REFSTOP | SP_REFSTART2 | SP_REFSTOP2
    1            1            null            null
   null         null            1               1
```

Thats a sample of the table.
I want to get values 1 and 1 on the 3rd and 4th column since first 2 are not null
but if there were null I want 1 and 1 in the first 2 (row 2nd example).

```
UPDATE STORETRADELINES
SET SP_REFRSTART2 = CASE WHEN SP_REFRSTART IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
```

I did that my it will take me many lines since the columns are more than the example so I was thinking if there is any if to set multiple values.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify your question.

Comment: Thats better i guess? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want `coalesce()`?

```
update STORETRADELINES
    set SP_REFSTART = coalesce(SP_REFSTART, SP_REFSTART2),
        SP_REFSTOP = coalesce(SP_REFSTOP, SP_REFSTOP2),
        SP_REFSTART2 = coalesce(SP_REFSTART2, SP_REFSTART),
        SP_REFSTOP2 = coalesce(SP_REFSTOP2, SP_REFSTOP)
```

Comment: Could you explain me a bit how it works? Because i think an if else but i dont know exactly how to set it up . Since what i want is If 2 first columns are not null to set the 2 last else i want the first 2 get the values.

Comment: @MixMasteR . . . Coalesce returns the first value from its arguments that is not `NULL`.

Comment: The values are usually text i used number 1 just for an example so basically i was thinking

`update storetradeliens
 set SP_REFSTART2 = 'some text value',SP_REFSTOP2 = 'some text value'
 when SP_REFSTART is not null and SP_REFSTOP is not null 
 else (here i want to set refstart and refstop the same values because there are null)`

Comment: @MixMasteR . . . `coalesce()` works with strings too.

Comment: Cool then so where do i insert the value in the following code you gave me e.g. value is 1 
` update STORETRADELINES
    set SP_REFSTART = coalesce(SP_REFSTART, SP_REFSTART2) `
where do i use it here.

Comment: If you want a specific value to be assigned to a null value, then that would be the second argument to `coalesce()`.